# Extracting tags from a HTML with data hidden using python

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm trying to learn scraping from different webpages. I tried to scrape data from a page containing tabs as follows:

```
url = "https://www.bc.edu/bc-web/schools/mcas/departments/art/people/#par-bc_tabbed_content-tab-0"
page = requests.get(url)
content = page.content
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
p = soup.find_all('div',{"id":'e6bde0e9_358d_4966_8fde_be96e9dcad0b'})
print p
```

This returns empty result
Though inspecting the element displays the content but the source page doesn't display this data. Any pointers on how to extract the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of javascript rendering, which means that the data you want doesn't come with the original request, but requests generated by the javascript of that response.

To check ALL the requests that were generated by the original request, you'll have to use something like `developer tools` in Chrome.

For this particular case the actual request you need is to this [site](https://www.bc.edu/content/bc-web/schools/mcas/departments/art/people/jcr:content/par/bc_tabbed_content/tab-0/bc_faculty_page_sect.individual-items.html), which will give you the information you need.

Comment: The site contains the "individual-items", can you please tell me where from it has been extracted? I couldn't find any using developer tools.

Comment: I got it! I didn't realise it must be searched in networks.